# Magento transactional email template variables assigned are not used by template

Tags: email-templates

I am trying to send custom email with some variables in it, but don't know what I am doing wrong in it
here is my code :

```
    $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
    $emailTemplate->loadByCode('custom_email_template');
    //$emailTemplate->loadDefault('custom_email_template');
    //$emailTemplate->load($templateId);
    /* tried all of the above to load template but same results */
    $emailTemplate->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email'));
    $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name'));


    $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($templateVariables);

    try {
        $emailTemplate->send($rec_email, $rec_name, $templateVariables);
    }
    catch(Exception $ex) {
        echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__($ex->getMessage()));
    }
```

I added the template from Magento admin panel transactional emails, haven't created any html file for template.

Email is getting sent but variables are shown as

```
{{ var sender_name }}

{{ var rcver_name }}

{{ var pr_name }}

{{ var order_number }}
```

Please give me an idea of what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove start and end spaces from the template variables like

```
{{var sender_name}}

{{var rcver_name}}

{{var pr_name}}

{{var order_number}}
```